# why can't I embed youtube in 720HD or have full screen button in windows 8 Webview?

Tags: c#, windows-8, webview, youtube, windows-store-apps

According to
[embed youtube html5 player shows no fullscreen button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597956/embed-youtube-html5-player-shows-no-fullscreen-button)

I should be able to get fullscreen button. But it doesn't work when I tried to embed youtube in webview, it only shows a basic youtube player with no full screen button and low resolution video by default

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        string videoID = "lP7SSJSj1NM";
        string videoWidth = "800";
        string videoHeight = "480";

        string videoSrc = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID + @"?autoplay=1&vq=hd720";

        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append(@"<body style=""padding:0; margin:0"" >");

        html.Append(@"<iframe frameborder=""0"" style=""padding:0; margin:0"" width=""" + videoWidth + @""" height=""" + videoHeight + @""" src=" + videoSrc + " allowfullscreen=" + @"""1" + @"""></iframe>");

        html.Append(@"</body>");
        myWebView.NavigateToString(html.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I used this try it

```
contentViewBorder.Width = 1305;
            contentView.Width = 1305;
            contentViewBorder.Height = 800;
            contentView.Height = 800;

            contentView.Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(-520, -210, (490), 1500);
```